# Buzz problem in Ibanez RG350dxz

Tags: guitar, sound, noise, buzz, wiring

I was cleaning up my guitar and removed my edge ii tremelo bridge and the springs holding it along with the stud screws holding the blade. But now when I reconnected everything, there is no sound other than a buzz whose intensity changes when I touch the pickups. Please help me figure this out. Any suggestion would be helpful.. It's killing me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you removed the screws, there should have been a ground strap attached to the claw that the springs connect to, or possibly to the tremelo itself.

If this is still attached then look at where the other end is connected - usually the ground plane or one of the pots. It may have come loose when you removed the trem.

Comment: Thanks. :D  Funny thing is, it was my cable that was damaged.. It was really stupid of me to have not checked properly..

Comment: Well, hope it's all good now. If the answer was useful, you can upvote and use the check mark to accept the answer. I hope you stick around - loads of guitarists here... I learn something new all the time.